# Login en formulario con Python CSRF

Tags: python, facebook

Estoy tratando de iniciar sesiÓn en Facebook con una aplicación hecha en `Python`. Este mismo código usado para este foro he de decir que me funciona, me loguea perfectamente. Como veis en el código tengo una parte en la que creo la cookie del token que la tengo en comentario ya que en Facebook no consigo averiguar cual de los muchos campos hidden es.

Ademas de esto he probado a hacer login en otras paginas donde aparecía un campo hidden con el nombre securitytoken y ni creando la cookie me funcionaba, por eso os pongo la pagina de Facebook que todo el mundo tiene cuenta, a ver si podeis probar el código y me echais una mano que estoy muy muy desesperado llevo ya 3 o 4 días probando cosas.

Sin más muchas gracias de antemano!!

```
import requests


url = "https://www.facebook.com/"


payload = {
    'email':'email',
    'password':'password',
    'submit':'Entrar'
}

s = requests.Session()

#sttoken = s.cookies['securitytoken']
#print("El token es ",sttoken)

logueo = s.post(url, data=payload)
r = s.get("http://www.facebook.com/")

if( (logueo.status_code)  == 200 ):
    print("Peticion de login aceptada")
else:
    print("El login esta fallando")

if ('Nombre_usuario' in r.text):
    print("Has realizado el login correctamente")
    print(r.text)
else:
    print('Fallo, no te has autenticado correctamente')
```

Answer (score 1):

Para manejar webs yo uso otra librería muy potente y versátil. Se trata de *Selenium*. Puedes encontrar abundante bibliografía al respecto y puedes hacer creo que casi cualquier cosa que se te ocurra con una web. Si quisiera iniciar sesión en *Facebook*, haría lo siguiente después de instalar *Selenium*, `selenium (pip install selenium)`:

```
from selenium import webdriver

# Con esto abres el navegador
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# Con esto navegas al sitio que desees
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com')

# Con esto localizas el input de usuario y contraseña
input_email = driver.find_element_by_id('email')
input_password = driver.find_element_by_id('pass')

# Con esto introduces los datos de login
input_email.send_keys('user@mail.com')
input_password.send_keys('userpass')

# Para entrar puedes o bien hacer submit en algún campo del formulario o bien buscar el botón y hacer click
# 1 - Haciendo submit (Mi favorita)
input_password.submit()

# 2 - Buscando el botón (Hay que buscar el id, o el texto, o algo identificativo del mismo. Hay muchas formas de hacerlo)
# EnterButton = driver.find_element_by_id('u_0_o')
# EnterButton.click()
```

Con eso ya estás dentro de tu sesión de *Facebook*. Ahora puedes investigar más de *Selenium* y verás lo fácil que es obtener sesiones, cookies, saltar de una página a otra, en fin... puedes hacer muchas cosas.

También hay una aplicación que se llama *PhantomJS* que se puede sustituir por `Firefox()` y en este caso, no verías el navegador abrirse pero puedes hacer lo mismo, solo cambiaría la sentencia:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

por este otra:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(r'C/ruta/dondetengas/elfichero/phantomjs.exe')
```

Puedes descargarlo y ver más información aqui http://phantomjs.org/.

Si estás comenzando te recomiendo que uses `Firefox()` para que veas bien lo que hace y te sea más fácil detectar los errores que vaya teniendo.